# Loading dates from core data

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, nsdate

I have a view with lots of labels, each one corresponding to a week day and a type of task. I want to load information from core data and use that information to set each label's text.

```
#import "WeekViewController.h"

@implementation WeekViewController

- (void) viewDidLoad {

    gregorian = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
    [gregorian setFirstWeekday:2];

    mondayMeetings = 0;
    mondayPhoneCalls = 0;
    mondayToDos = 0;

    tuesdayMeetings = 0;
    tuesdayPhoneCalls = 0;
    tuesdayToDos = 0;

    wednesdayMeetings = 0;
    wednesdayPhoneCalls = 0;
    wednesdayToDos = 0;

    thursdayMeetings = 0;
    thursdayPhoneCalls = 0;
    thursdayToDos = 0;

    fridayMeetings = 0;
    fridayPhoneCalls = 0;
    fridayToDos = 0;

    saturdayMeetings = 0;
    saturdayPhoneCalls = 0;
    saturdayToDos = 0;

    sundayMeetings = 0;
    sundayPhoneCalls = 0;
    sundayToDos = 0;

    [self loadInfo:[NSDate date]];

}

- (void) loadInfo:(NSDate *)date {

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(Date >= %@) AND (Date <= %@)", [self dateByMovingToBeginningOfWeek:self.selectedDate], [self dateByMovingToEndOfWeek:self.selectedDate]];

    request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Task" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Date" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    [sortDescriptors release];
    [sortDescriptor release];

    NSError *error = nil;

    mutableFetchResults = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
    if (mutableFetchResults == nil) {

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < [mutableFetchResults count]; i++) {

        Task *aTask = (Task *)[mutableFetchResults objectAtIndex:i];

        NSDateComponents *comps = [gregorian components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:aTask.Date];

        int weekday = [comps weekday];

        if (weekday == 1  && [aTask.Type isEqualToString:@"PhoneCall"]) {

            mondayPhoneCalls ++;

        }

    }

    NSLog(@"%d", mondayPhoneCalls);

    for (UILabel *go in [self.view subviews]) {

        if (go.tag == 1) {

            go.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", mondayPhoneCalls];

        }

    }

}

- (NSDate *) dateByMovingToEndOfWeek:(NSDate *)date {
    unsigned int flags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;

    NSDateComponents *parts = [gregorian components:flags fromDate:date];

    [parts setWeekday:7];
    [parts setHour:23];
    [parts setMinute:59];
    [parts setSecond:59];

    return [gregorian dateFromComponents:parts];

}

- (NSDate *) dateByMovingToBeginningOfWeek:(NSDate *)date {

    unsigned int flags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;

    NSDateComponents *parts = [gregorian components:flags fromDate:date];

    [parts setWeekday:0];
    [parts setHour:0];
    [parts setMinute:0];
    [parts setSecond:0];

    return [gregorian dateFromComponents:parts];

}

@end
```

But it only registers a task if it's date is the current date(sunday by the way). Also can anyone think of a more efficient way to set each label's text than either having an outlet for each one, or looping through all of the view's subviews and checking their tags?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your predicate is now saying "objects whose date is today's date or later AND whose date is today's date or earlier". The only objects who fulfill that requirement are the ones with today date.

For your other question, you can look at an IBOutletCollection. They are used for collections of similar objects (in your case UILabel). It's basically an NSArray of IB objects, which you can loop over and easily set their values.

Comment: Really? what I have tried to do is only load dates that are in the same week as the selected date. I planned to do this by using two methods one of which returns the end of the week the selected date is in and the other returns the beginning of the week. So my predicate is at least supposed to say "objects whose date is the beginning of the week or later AND the end of the week or earlier"

Comment: I'm sorry, missed that part. Looks like your predicate is correct. I suspect it's your dateByMoving methods. You set the NSDayCalendarUnit flag, but then you change the weekday to 7 leaving the original day as is. That's like saying "give me the date for Saturday, November 3, 2012"--it doesn't exist. Verify those methods by making sure the NSDate objects they return are correct.